# Get rails associated objects with React

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

After setup a simple post associated user model with rails i'd like to get the post owner avatar  with react but all that i get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username''avatar' etc.. of undefined

I've tried to get the associated post user on fetching the post

```
async getPost() {
    // this.setState({showProgress: true})

let {
  match: { params }
} = this.props;

const response = await axios
  .get(`/posts/${params.id}`, {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "same-origin"
  })

  .then(result => {
    this.setState({
      title: result.data.post.title,
      user: result.data.post.user.username,
      user: result.data.post.user,

     url: result.data.post.user.avatar.post.url
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });


}
```

but Still showing error on the log and the user that is filled with the post is the user_id

So, someone has any hint to spare about this?

Comment: could you show the result of `console.log(result)` so that it will be easy to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your returned data does not include user information. In your ajax call response, you cannot query as if you are in rails controller.

In your case, you should return user information together with post in your controller action.

```
post = Post.find(params[:id])
user = post.user
post = post.as_json
post[:user] = user.as_json

render json: { post: post }
```

If you need users information for multiple posts, you can use eager loading in your rails controller action

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user).all.map do |post|
           post_json = post.as_json
           post_json[:user] = post.user.as_json
           post_json
         end

render json: { posts: @posts }
```

Comment: quyetdc that's it, thank you very much for your answer!